# Getting Moment JS to display time ago up to yesterday then start displaying a formatted date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

Disclaimer: I'm very new to javascript (and angular).

I'm trying to get momentjs to display the time from now up till yesterday. Once it's been 3 days it would display the actual date.

Example using random date (date diff will always be "today"):

- 10/10/17 at 6:41 pm (future)
- Tomorrow at 6:41 pm
- Today at 6:41 pm
- Yesterday at 6:41 pm
- 10/10/17 at 6:41 pm

Not sure what other information I should provide but please ask if anything helps.

Comment: you should add what you have already tried. However you can just check if date is today/yesterday/tomorrow and in that case just do moment.format('string format')

Comment: @binariedMe I've tried searching though couldn't find any posts looking to do what I'm doing. I'm currently using standard format `{{n.created_at | moment : 'format' : 'M/D/YY [at] h:mm a'}}` which display a date as "10/10/17 at 6:41 pm" but does not display "Today", etc.

Comment: no, you will have to check if the date given is today/tomorrow/yesterday to show particular string and it won't be out of the box supported at all in moment.js. Just make a custom pipe and check if given date is t/t/y

Comment: @binariedMe Creating custom pipe for an unsupported feature is likely beyond my abilities at this time. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: you can instead make a function getDisplayDate which you can call from front end instead of using pipe so something like this : {{getDisplayDate(n.created_at)}} and implement the logic there by putting some checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for input. Using your examples I was able to solve the problem. Shortly after I found a much better way to do what I wanted which I will share here.

Using momentJS calendar feature makes doing this very simple. Here is my filter which does precisely what I wanted plus a some extra features.

```js
//This filter will display today, tomorrow, yesterday then display the actual date as 'M/D/Y at h:mm a'.
//Default preposition is 'at', but any other can be passed in as the second parameter.
.filter('formatForTimeAgo', function () {
  return function timeTodayDateElse(date, preposition){
    preposition=preposition|| 'at'
    moment.lang('en', {
      'calendar' : {
        'lastDay'  : '[Yesterday] [\n][ '+preposition+' ] h:mm a',
        'sameDay'  : '[Today] [\n][ '+preposition+' ] h:mm a',
        'nextDay'  : '[Tomorrow] [\n][ '+preposition+' ] h:mm a',
        'lastWeek' : 'M/D/YY [\n]['+preposition+'] h:mm a',
        'nextWeek' : 'M/D/YY [\n]['+preposition+'] h:mm a',
        'sameElse' : 'M/D/YY [\n]['+preposition+'] h:mm a'
       }
    });
    return moment(date).calendar();
  }
})
```

`{{yourDate | }}` after formatting will appear like this: `Today at 10:17 pm`, `Yesterday at 10:17 pm`, or `Tomorrow at 10:17 pm`. Once +/- 2 days it will display as a numerical date, eg `9/13/17 at 10:17 pm`.

You can insert a custom preposition (defaulted to "at") with a second parameter. 
Example: `{{yourDate | formatForTimeAgo : 'by'}}` will change "at" to "by" so you get `Today by 10:17 pm`, `Yesterday by 10:17 pm`, etc.

Once again, thank you. This was a great learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of functions that can be helpful in getting the expected output.

1. `moment.format()`: You can use it to format the string like you want it. For example: `moment.format("dd/MM/YY at hh:mm:ss")`
2. `moment.isSame()`: To determine if the date is same as today.
3. `moment.diff()`: To determine the differece between dates.

Here's a solution based on what you expect the output to be:
https://jsfiddle.net/3ruv8aj3/

Comment: The fiddle above is a rough solution based on expected outputs and can be improved further.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much you've familiarized with moment so far, so here's one way to do it, from the beginning:

```
// get today's date and time
var now = moment();

// will hold our display string (we'll set this in a minute)
var displayValue = '';

// target date & time in string format (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm)
// you can also use a JavaScript date object instead of a string
var dateString = '2017-10-10 06:41';

// create a moment wrapper for the past/future date
var targetDate = moment(dateString);

// how many total days difference between then and now?
// calling moment() with no args defaults to current date and time
// first argument to `diff` is the date to subtract
// second argument is the unit of time to measure in
var difference = now.diff(targetDate, 'days');

if (difference > 3 || difference < -3) {
    // if the date is more than three days in the past or more than three days into the future...
    displayValue = targetDate.format('MM-DD-YYYY') + ' at ' + targetDate.format('hh:mm');
} else {
    // otherwise...
    displayValue = targetDate.fromNow();
}

console.log(displayValue); // > "10-10-2017 at 06:41"
```

Edit: If the target date happens to be today, and you want to display 'Today' instead of moment's default '15 hours ago', just check for a difference of 0.

```
if (difference === 0) displayValue = 'Today at ' + targetDate.format('hh:mm');
```

Edit: Created a variable for 'now', for clarity.

Comment: Pretty green here so apologies if I'm interpreting incorrectly. Looks like you are setting the date I gave above and showing diff vs that date? The date will always be "today", as in the date of creation.

Comment: You need a date to check against though, correct? Something that has a past or future date associated with it?

Comment: This line checks against the current date: `var difference = moment().diff(targetDate, 'days');` So, anywhere you want to use today, you can use `moment()`. Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: I might be explaining incorrectly. Will try to explain the context in which this will be used. 

User will post a "note" and on the note it currently displays the date it was posted. I want to change the date to "Today" and "Yesterday" when applicable plus the time it was posted. This will always be compared to the real world current date. Sorry if I'm confusing your code or not being clear.

Comment: This accomplishes figuring out if any two dates are more than three days apart from each other, or showing a time-ago string otherwise. Use `moment()` anytime you want a value to represent today, and use `moment(otherDateValue)` anywhere you want a value to represent the other date.

Comment: To be clear, `moment()` equals "exactly right now". If you pass a date string or date object in, e.g. `moment('2020-04-01')` if will return an object representing the date specified.'

Comment: Original comment edited for clarity. Give the code a read-thru and see if that makes sense. `targetDate` would represent whenever the note was saved.

Comment: How would I implement this as a new filter?

Comment: This is a way to display a human-friendly string in your UI. Assuming by filter you mean some 'filter by date' functionality, I probably wouldn't try to implement that with any prettified values such as these, as they're not generated to be precise. (Another argument would be, what if later you want to display these as an icon? Then you have to rewrite your filter too.)